# No entiendo porque me toma el valor del CPU y me muestra otra cosa

Tags: javascript

Perdón pero soy novato, no logro entender porque no me muestra el **cpuResult**, me muestra resultados aleatorios, pero parece que la función esta ok.

```
let opcionUsuario;
let opcionCPU;
```

Ésto funciona ok!

```
const piedra = document.getElementById("piedra").onclick = () => {
opcionUsuario = piedra;
document.getElementById("playerResult").value = "Piedra";
play(opcionCPU, opcionUsuario);
}
const papel = document.getElementById("papel").onclick = () => {
  opcionUsuario = papel;
  document.getElementById("playerResult").value = "Papel";
  play(opcionCPU, opcionUsuario);
}
const tijera = document.getElementById("tijera").onclick = () => {
  opcionUsuario = tijera;
  document.getElementById("playerResult").value = "Tijera";
  play(opcionCPU, opcionUsuario);
}

const restart = document.getElementById("restart").onclick = () => {
  location.reload();
}
```

La parte del random o aleatorio también funciona bien, pero no me muestra los resultados que pongo en el **cpuResult**.

```
function aleatorio() {
    opcionCPU = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0 + 1) + 0);
    if(opcionCPU === 0) {
      document.getElementById("cpuResult").value = "Piedra";
    } else if(opcionCPU === 1) {
      document.getElementById("cpuResult").value = "Papel";
    } else if(opcionCPU === 2) {
      document.getElementById("cpuResult").value = "Tijera";
    }
  }

function play(opcionCPU, opcionUsuario){
  aleatorio();
  if(opcionCPU === 0 && opcionUsuario === piedra) {
    console.log("Empate");
  } else if(opcionCPU === 0 && opcionUsuario === papel) {
    console.log("Ganaste")
  } else if(opcionCPU === 0 && opcionUsuario === tijera) {
    console.log("Perdiste");
  } else if(opcionCPU === 1 && opcionUsuario === piedra) {
    console.log("Pediste");
  } else if(opcionCPU === 1 && opcionUsuario === papel) {
    console.log("empate");
  } else if(opcionCPU === 1 && opcionUsuario === tijera) {
    console.log("ganaste");
  } else if(opcionCPU === 2 && opcionUsuario === piedra) {
    console.log("ganaste") 
  } else if(opcionCPU === 2 && opcionUsuario === papel) {
    console.log("perdiste")
  } else if(opcionCPU === 2 && opcionUsuario === tijera) {
    console.log("empate");
  }
  console.log(opcionCPU)
 }
```

Es decir, parece que funciona bien el resto del código, pero no me muestra en el *HTML* los verdaderos resultados del random.

¿Alguien sabe por que? desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error conceptual a la hora de usar los *scopes* de la funciones.

La función `play` espera los parámetros `opcionCPU` y `opcionUsuario`. Dentro de esa función, se evalúa el valor del parámetro `opcionCPU`, que nunca ha cambiado.
Lo que sí cambia es el valor de la variable global `opcionCPU` (en la función `aleatorio`).

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo que ilustra el error

```
let a = -1;

function global() {
    a = 0;
    console.log('global a changed to ', a);
}

function scoped(a) {
    // global() cambia el valor de a global, no el parámetro a
    global();
    console.log('value of parameter a: ', a);
}

scoped(a);
// global a changed to  0
// value of parameter a:  -1
```

---

#### Posibles soluciones

- La función `aleatorio` devuelve el valor `opcionCPU` generado

```
function aleatorio() {
    const opcionCPU = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    // ...

    return opcionCPU;
}

// play ya no necesita el parámetro opcionCPU, 
// porque lo obtendrá de la función aleatorio
function play(opcionUsuario) {
    const opcionCPU = aleatorio();
    // ...
}
```

- Las dos funciones usan la misma variable global `opcionCPU`

```
let opcionCPU;

function aleatorio() {
    opcionCPU = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    // ...
}

// play ya no necesita el parámetro opcionCPU, 
// porque accederá a la variable global
function play(opcionUsuario) {
    aleatorio();
    // ...
}
```

Personalmente, prefiero la primera opción a menos que haya otros procesos que deban acceder a la misma variable global. Viendo por encima tu código, no es el caso.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!